# Adding a target to a button prints out an error

Tags: swift, button, selector

I have the following code:

```
for i in 0...album.count-1 {
    let button: UIButton = {
        let bt = UIButton()
        bt.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        bt.tintColor = UIColor.black
        bt.backgroundColor = .clear
        bt.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPressed(sender: button, image: imageView)), for: .touchUpInside)
        bt.tag = i
        buttonPosition += 160
        bt.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        return bt
    }()

    //Stuff that you don't need

    let imageView: UIImageView = {
        let iv = UIImageView()
        iv.image = images[i]
        iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        iv.clipsToBounds = true
        iv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return iv
    }()
}

@objc func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton!, image: UIImageView!) {
    let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator.init(duration: 0.2, curve: .linear) {
        image.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(translationX: (image.frame.width + 12) * -1, y: image.frame.origin.y )
    }
    animator.startAnimation()
}
```

It prints out this error:

> Variable used within its own initial value

What can I do to create a func that uses as parameters that button and that imageView that I created into the cycle?

In the end, how can I create a local func?

Answer (score 0):

You're referring to `button` from within the very closure that creates it (in the selector clause), which is why you're getting this error. It should work fine if you change `#selector(buttonPressed(sender: button, image: imageView))` to `#selector(buttonPressed(sender: bt, image: imageView))`. However, a cleaner way to do this would be to create a factory function, e.g.:

```
func makeButton(at position: CGFloat, taggedWith tag: Int) -> UIButton {
            let bt = UIButton()
            bt.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            bt.tintColor = UIColor.black
            bt.backgroundColor = .clear
            bt.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPressed(sender: button, image: imageView)), for: .touchUpInside)
            bt.tag = tag
            /// buttonPosition += 160 /// not sure what this is supposed to do but you'd use the position param here. 
            bt.layer.cornerRadius = 5
            return bt
}
```

You would then call this function to make buttons in your loop. Note that `buttonPosition` appears to be unused. Also note that your buttons weren't added to a collection or a view so you may want to examine where the buttons are supposed to live and place them accordingly.

Comment: I have the constraints later in the code ;) tomorrow I’ll try to implement your suggestions in my code. Should I use a collection view, is this what you are telling me?

Comment: I’m trying to re-create a table view without using a default table view, and when I tap on a button the buttons that live under the one tapped need to go down and let a new view come into the scroll view

Comment: Sorry, by collection I meant a data structure like an array or a dictionary, in which you'd store the references to your buttons, if that was something you needed. But right now, your function is creating and then immediately throwing away the buttons it creates. If your buttons are meant to be a repeating element in a table view then I don't recommend this approach at all since table rows, along with their content, are meant to be reusable.

Comment: It seems like you're trying to create an accordion-like behavior (tapped row expands/collapses pushing down/pulling up content below or above it). If you search around (try "accordion table view"), you'll find numerous examples of what you're trying to achieve. However, you don't really need buttons at all if you're using a table view, unless your buttons implement _additional_ functionality that is different from the row tap action (`func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`). If you only need to respond to row taps, I'd use this delegate method instead

Comment: It’s an exercise: I’m trying to reproduce a table view, but with some more things